# Google Developer Couldn't create OAuth client for Google sign in

Tags: android, android-studio, google-developers-console

I'm trying to use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/ to make log in with google inside my android app, but when trying to configure a project using my project package ans SHA1 key I got this error

```
Couldn't create OAuth client
warning
Requested entity already exists
```

I searched if I create a project before with this package and SHA and find my co-worker using it in a previous project he tried to add it and got the same warning then he deleted it and I try using my project again but the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find a fix for this problem, or any hint what can be the cause?

Comment: I didn't find a fix for that issue but can work by another way, I use the project which I created for my application on firebase and it works but there is a problem with that it only works on debug version and on release it gives a failed error with code 10

Comment: Error code 10 stands for developer error. Probably it has problem with sha1 and cert you use.

Comment: another way might be adding OAuth client directly from your cloud console account.

Comment: it fixed now by adding the sha1 for release I found the problem of only working on debug because I added the debug sha1 only. thanks for helping @Valdemar

Comment: No problem Amin, good luck with your project.